# Aggregate functions with EF repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

Lets say that I have a products catalog MVC web application that utilizes EF 6.0 where all CRUD operations are handled by repositories. Now, one of the views has to show a `List` of `Categories` along with some aggregate information about `Products` from that `Category`, I mean that next to `Category` name column should appear three columns with total count of products from that category, along with minimum and maximum prices of products.

```
public class Product
{
    public string   Name    { get; set; }
    public decimal  Price   { get; set; }
    public int      CategoryId             { get; set; }
    public virtual  Category    Category   { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string   Name    { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Product>   Products   { get; set; }
}
```

Then if I have a repository of Bakery products

```
unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Insert(new Product(){Name="Doughnut", Price=4.0, CategoryId=1});
unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Insert(new Product(){Name="Apple Pie", Price=7.0, CategoryId=1});
unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Insert(new Product(){Name="Meat Pie", Price=9.0, CategoryId=1});
```

I need the view to show

```
#  Category        Total Products        Min Price        Max Price
1  Bakery products 3                     4                9
```

I don't believe that it is a bright idea to handle out of the repository the query, since it ruins all the idea of using repositories, and AFAIK it's widely recognized as a bad practice.
Some queries that utilize the `DbContext` directly could be written but I wanted to know how this type of tasks is handled in real world applications?
Maybe a new view model is required and then another read-only repository should be added that will get this data? Something like this?

```
public class CategoryStatsVM
{
    public string   Name    { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Product>   Products   { get; set; }
    public int      Count   { get; set; }
    public decimal  MinPrice    { get; set; }
    public decimal  MaxPrice    { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is not caused by EF (which `DbContext` **is** Repository and UOW and supports easily such scenarios) but from additional abstractions (limitations) you put on top on it, so please remove the `entity-framework` tag.

Comment: @IvanStoev I was following Microsoft's article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application that explains how to implement Repository and UoW on top of EF, so yes, I have an additional abstraction, but I want to understand how people deal with these problems when they follow Microsoft's docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure by what you mean by "I don't believe that it is a bright idea to handle out of the repository the query, since it ruins all the idea of using repositories".
The main idea behind a repository is to abstract away DATA ACCESS. If you want to do some aggregation, some other calculation or something like that, that's mostly part of your business logic. The VM is the component that requires you to do the count, the max and the min. The VM is basically an abstract view, and views are usually derived from business requirements. So I think doing these queries are not part of the data access, thus not part of the repository.
What I would do is add a method to the repository interface like this:

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetById(int i)
{
    return dbContext.Category.Single(c=>c.CategoryId==i);
}
```

And then in the business logic you can use it like this:

```
unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.GetById(3).Products.Count();
unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.GetById(3).Products.Min(p=>p.Price);
```

This also has the added benefit of not loosing the deferred execution of LInQ to Entities, so the counting and looking for the minimum will be executed on the database.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, but I believe you've got me wrong, I want to show a grid with a list of `Categories` and I don't want to run dozens of queries to build it. And to understand what I mean by saying that returning IQueryable<T> is a bad idea you can read f.e. this article http://codetunnel.io/should-you-return-iqueryablet-from-your-repositories/ and many others, just google it. But again, I'm not saying that this is the right way to do things, I'm just trying to understand how this should be accomplished if I follow best practices...

Comment: Thanks for the blog post. I don't necessarily agree, but it's always good to read other opinions.

Comment: Totally agree with you, that's why I'm asking here. If you could can think of something that can work with my constraints I would be grateful if you share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @Ivan Stoev. DbContext IS Repository. It handles all the basic CRUD operations and another repository layer on top of it seems to be redundant. What you're talking about sounds rather as a business layer that calls repository for "raw" data, apply additional logic and provide data to presentation layer.

So in your case you would have a service/business factory/class - whatever you call it - with a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryStatsVM> GetCategoryStats() 
{
    IList<Category> categories = dbContext.Categories.Include(m => m.Products).ToList();

    foreach (Category category in categories)
    {
        yield return new CategoryStatsVM
        {
            Name = category.Name,
            Count = category.Products.Count(),
            Products = this.GetProducts(category.Products),
            MinPrice = category.Products.Aggregate(GetMinPrice),
            MaxPrice = category.Products.Aggregate(GetMaxPrice) 
        }
    }
}

private Product GetMinPrice(Product min, Product current)
{
    return min == null || curr.Price < min.Price ? curr : min;
}

private Product GetMaxPrice(Product max, Product current)
{
    return max == null || curr.Price > max.Price ? curr : max;
}

private IEnumerable<ProductVM> GetProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    List<ProductVM> products; // create instance of the product view model list
    return products;
}
```

Just one note about the last function - It's there because you should create a view model class for the product too. You shouldn't work with data models in presentation layer.

I created separated functions for the aggregation just to make it more readable. you can of course have everything in one method:

```
MinPrice = category.Products.Aggregate((min, curr) => min == null || curr.Price < min.Price ? curr : min),
```

Comment: If you use `IEnumerable` like this, you will lose a lot on performance. You read all the category objects into memory to do the count, instead of letting the `IQueryable` be converted into a SQL query, performed by the database and return just a number.

Comment: Just by using members type of IEnumerable doesn't mean you load all objects into memory. IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable too. Variable definitions don't affect execution of the code. It's what you do with the query that determines whether you work with objects in memory or if you make database calls when the objects are needed. It's the first line in the GetCategoryStats that loads everything in memory, the .ToList() method. If it's better this way or not, depends on other logic, database structure, number of items, etc. But IEnumerable doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, but I meant exactly what you said by 'If you use IEnumerable __like this__'. I should have been more clear and add that I also meant the 'ToList()'. And this way you don't provide any control to the using component to decide when to execute. If you leave the IQueryable and the query itself, you leave the option of controlling query execution and even composition, which are important features.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I don't want to argue, but if this layer of abstraction is redundant why would Microsoft publish this article?- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Honestly. That's exactly what I was asking couple years ago :) I used to use this pattern too and I'm pretty sure it was exactly this article that I had read before. The only reasonable argument is that with this pattern described in the article, you can easily switch from EF to something else and keep the business layer untouched. But that's just the theory. Practice is usually not that simple :)

Comment: I believe that in world of Microsoft theory and reality usually aren't going hand in hand:), but again I want to see if anyone is following these practices, and how they deal with these tasks since,.. it's not that uncommon...

Comment: Changing the data access technology really is a benefit. We're just doing that in one our our projects: migrating fromt EF6 to EFCore. Granted it is a smaller project and some modification was required, but without using repository and unit-of-work, I think it would much more of a pain. And in my experience this separation is not the only advantage. Mocking the DAL is a lot easier for me if there are repositories; mocking `DbContect` properly is a challenge.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I'm refrain from migrating to EFCore until the second version is released(at least), and it lacks lot of things EF 6.0 has...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Aggregate function like this to get the UserLogs last logging of transaction file

```
UsersLogs.Where(i => i.Id== _id).Max(x => x.transId)
```